# How can I give a VBS script access to run without opening a security hole in IE?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer-8, vbscript, activex

I'm currently working on an application that basically sits on top of IE.  This program is used on Windows XP and Windows 7 laptops in police cars.  The program has a number of VB scripts that run, allowing the officer to do vehicle lookups and such.

Each function has its own VBS script and there is a central Functions script with common functions used by many of the individual scripts.  Each of the scripts has an include entry for the function script, however my current problem is that in Windows 7 with IE8, its not allowing that Functions script to run.  If I allow IE to initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting, it runs just fine.

Is there a way I can mark that VBS script as safe or allowed?  Or put it in a different location that would make it allowed?  If the officers didn't have internet access, I wouldn't be terribly concerned, but since they do, it creates an big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you VBS scripts running from?

If it a consistant location your could add that location to the "Trusted" section of IE and allow the ActiveX controls to run from there but not from other locations?

Comment: The VBScripts are all running from the local machine.  I ultimately ended up putting a fake Mark of the Web in, forcing the page to load in the Local Machine environment and adjusted the security settings in the registry to allow the script to run.